# loop in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, series

i have this problem looping through this dataframe, its printing the same column for each value

thanks

```
mycolumns = ['Date']
fd = pd.DataFrame(columns=mycolumns)

for key in data["Time"].items():
    a = fd.append(
        pd.Series(
            [
                date,
            ],
            index=mycolumns
        ),
        ignore_index=True
    )
    print(a)

output:

                  Date
0  2021-12-09 23:30:00
                  Date
0  2021-12-09 23:30:00
                  Date
0  2021-12-09 23:30:00
                  Date
0  2021-12-09 23:30:00
```

Comment: what is `data`?

Comment: Change `date` to `key`

Comment: its a request. data = requests.get(base_url, params=params).json()

Answer (score 0):

It appears as if the variable 'date' is the same in every iteration of your loop.

You are never using 'key' inside your loop.

Comment: i dont uderstand you, doesnt matter if im not using key i need a variable to loop in..

Comment: The value of 'date' never changes in any iteration of your loop.  It is being set in some part of your code that is not being shown.  That is why you are printing the same thing every time.  'key' is the variable that is changing, and you aren't using it.

Comment: you're right, now is changing but its still printing the column  Date
0  2021-12-30 19:00:00
                  Date
0  2021-12-30 18:30:00
                  Date
0  2021-12-30 18:00:00
                  Date